# Flutter variable shared between 2 pages

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have a page with a list and a other page with filter.
I would like to have a shared variable between these two pages.
So that when I close my filter page I can filter my list.
I saw `BehaviorSubject` which looks good for listening but I don't know how to use it on 2 different pages.

What is the best path for this?

Thanks,

Comment: You need a state management library.
Provider is easy and works perfectly well.

Check this out https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: Thanks, I have use my bloc for provider and it's works !